# Magento 1 - Color Picker does not show in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, backend, development

I developed a extension where you can set specific settings in the backend. I made an input field which should spawn a color picker on click.

[image]

It works great on Magento 1.8 but fails with Magento 1.9.

This is how I defined it:

```
<subscribe_bgcolor>
    <label>Anmelden Hintergrund Farbe</label>
    <comment>Hex Code</comment>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <validate>color</validate>
    <sort_order>35</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</subscribe_bgcolor>
```

I used `<frontend_type>text</frontend_type>` and `<validate>color</validate>`, but no color picker is getting spawned.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on this :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784800/color-picker-in-magento-admin-panel